# Extern a type in C

Tags: c, typedef, extern

I am trying to figure out a way to create a "template" type in C, which I can override by specific implementation. Right now I have a specific type defines in a header file:

```
typedef enum
{
    enumItem = 0,
} mytype_t;
```

What I am looking for is to somehow "extern" the type in the header and provide this specific implementation in the source file.

```
extern typedef enum mytype_t; // pseudocode
```

Is that possible in C?

EDIT:

The exact reason I am looking for such a solution, is the fact that:

1. I need to have an enum in the header that's visible to multiple file including the header.
2. One of the enum items is assigned with a `#define` from a different header file- this file I would not like to be re-included along with the enum, but at the same time the enum needs to know it.
3. This is why I though a good solution would be to hide the exact enum implementation in the C source file and only expose a "template" in the header.

This problem can be solved in a variable ways. But since it has arised, I wanted to research whether such a proposed mechanism is possible to accomplish somehow in C.

Comment: You can simply provide the actual type definition (what you call "specific implementation") at the start of the source file, and it will be used by all header files that are included afterwards and by all code that follows. I don't understand why you see the need for an "extern" type. Exactly what kind of problem are you attempting to solve?

Comment: What I am trying to do is to allow for generic modules to use a type, without yet knowing what is it exactly- this is to be defined only after implementation is provided. I don't understand your proposal- could you show an example?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you write "without yet knowing what it is"? When will it be known? Later during compilation? Or only at run-time? If it will be known later during compilation, why do you not simply move the actual type definition to the start of the source file, so that it is known earlier?

Comment: Does the problem you are trying to solve involve only a single `.c` source file (translation unit)? Or multiple `.c` source files? (I am not asking about header files.)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "use a type"? What kind of operations should be performed on the type? Would it be sufficient for the "generic module" to only have a `void *` to the object, so that it can perform operations on the object without having any knowledge of its type?

Comment: In this case the enum members definitions would be different  depending on which C file is used in the project. All this should be resolved at compile time.

Comment: I believe what you are asking for is not possible in C. However, I have the impression that you are asking about an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Therefore, it would probably be helpful if you [edit] the question to give a short example of a problem an "extern" type definition would solve, so that we can maybe offer an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to hide an enum in C the way you want.

It would not be very useful even if you could because enums are just integral types and all integral types are implicitly convertible to each other.

```
  typedef enum { one, two } Some;
  typedef enum { uno, dos } Other;
                              
  int main()
  {   
      int a = 0;
      Some b = one;
      Other c = uno;
      
      a = b; a = c;
      b = a; c = a;
      c = b;
  }
```

It's all perfectly legal C. Some compilers won't warn you about this with the normal warning level (gcc -Wall) and others won't warn you at all even with the highest warning setting (MSVC).

So you can just use

```
typedef int mytype_t;
```

and no one will be able to tell the difference (almost).

If you need something like a strong typedef, use this

```
typedef struct mytype_s { int value; } mytype_t;
```

and use enumerators defined in a C file with it.